# EV3 touch sensor specs relevant for a brick-built MOC

Tags: ev3, piece-information

I want to integrate the following EV3 touch sensors (45507) into a MOC:

[image: EV3 touch sensor]

For aesthetic reasons, I want the MOC to be mainly built out of system bricks and plates, with only some internal stuff in Technic (basically just connectors and beams to hold the EV3 parts).

I'd like to know what offset in plate height or stud width I'm looking at when the button is pressed or not pressed.

Also I'd like to know how much weight there can be on the button before the EV3 will consider it pressed or bumped.

Comment: The first question is easy. The full travel of the button is 1/2 stud. The second question (about weight) probably depends somewhat on the individual sensor. Maybe I will get out my scales and see what it is later.

Comment: This paper has information on NXT touch sensors: https://bibliotecadigital.ipb.pt/bitstream/10198/2262/1/Proceedings_10thConferenceMobileRobotsCompetitions.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how accurate my rig is, but I get something like 2 millimeters of travel before the touch sensor is "pressed". The HiTechnic Force sensor doesn't seem to give an accurate measurement, but according to my kitchen scales, it takes about 80g force (0.8N) to trigger the sensor.

[image: photo of test rig with touch sensor, force sensor, calipers, EV3]

Comment: Incredible dedication to anwer this question!